# Dynamic for set in batches

Tags: list, dynamic, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I want 2 types of lists
The first list with types for example daily and release and the second type with paths for the first list.
After that I want dynamicly go through the second type lists based on the first type list.

Something like that:

```
@ECHO OFF

REM ##########
REM ## Test ##
REM ##########

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

SET VersionType=(Daily Release)
SET TagetsDaily=(path1 path2)
SET TagetsRelease=(path23 path24)


FOR %%n IN %VersionType% DO (
    ECHO !Tagets%%n!
    SET test_temp=!Tagets%%n!
    ECHO %test_temp%

    FOR %%i !Tagets%%n! DO (
        ECHO %%i
    )
)

PAUSE
EXIT
```

The problem of this code is that it doesn't worked.

OUTPUT:

```
"!Tagets%n!" can be syntactically processed at this point.
```

And with out the secound for its:

```
(path1 path2)
ECHO is off (OFF).
(path23 path24)
ECHO is off (OFF).
```

Can me anyone explain me why thats is a syntactic error and why I can copy the content from !Tagets%%n! into an other variable??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "VersionType=Daily Release"
SET "TagetsDaily=path1 path2"
SET "TagetsRelease=path23 path24"

FOR %%n IN (%VersionType%) DO (
     ECHO !Tagets%%n!
     SET test_temp=!Tagets%%n!
     ECHO !test_temp!

     FOR %%i IN (!Tagets%%n!) DO (
          ECHO %%i
     )
)
```

Please look at `for /?` and `delayed expansion`.

Comment: thank you very much.
That meens for paths with whitespaces this:

`code`
SET "TagetsRelease="C:\Hello World\test23.txt" "C:\Hello World\test24.txt""

Or is there something wrong to?

Comment: you can use `set "file=C:\hello world\test.txt"`